# Decorate a template with Twig instead of including it

Tags: php, templates, twig, decorator

I'm working on a small ORM for my work, based on an **Active Record** system. So all models extend a generated base model (for example : `Foo` will extends `BaseFoo`, the abstract `BaseFoo` class will be generated by a command).

The abstract model generation is based on a Twig template, including some parts of other templates (attributes, getters & setters, main methods, etc).

But the ORM must handle a behavior system. So a behavior should be able to decorate the main template. But with the Twig hierarchical layout system, I don't find a way to properly decorate my template, by injecting some lines in the main template. I can handle it with the `embed` tag, calling the base template and overriding `blocks`. But when there is more than one behavior, the idea fails because the `embed` tag rewrites the main template so it will write twice times the model (`class BaseFoo { code overrided by behavior1 } class BaseFoo { code overrided by behavior2 }`.

I thought about creating some new tags : `replace "line" by "line"`, `append "line" after "line"` or `prepend "line" before "line"`. But I want to be sure that there isn't a better way to decorate a Twig template, like for example, generating one by one the template for all behaviors : the first behavior will override the main template and the next behavior will override the previous generated template by calling the Twig function `template_from_string()`.

What do you think about the possibility of decorating a Twig template ?

Comment: Why are you using Twig in your Model layer? Twig is used to handle views. I would avoid tying my Model's to my views if possible as the Controller is generally supposed to glue the Model and View together.